# Pear packages installing but not found afterwards

Tags: php, package, pear, package-managers

I am working on a mac and trying to install http_request2 and mail_mime via the pear package manager.

When I use the pear install command I see this:

```
$ pear install http_request2
downloading HTTP_Request2-2.2.1.tgz ...
Starting to download HTTP_Request2-2.2.1.tgz (107,339 bytes)
.........................done: 107,339 bytes
downloading Net_URL2-2.0.5.tgz ...
Starting to download Net_URL2-2.0.5.tgz (17,456 bytes)
...done: 17,456 bytes
install ok: channel://pear.php.net/Net_URL2-2.0.5
install ok: channel://pear.php.net/HTTP_Request2-2.2.1
```

Which leads me to believe that this is installed correctly. However, if I  then run pear list -a I get the following output:

```
$ pear list -a
Installed packages, channel __uri:
==================================
(no packages installed)

Installed packages, channel doc.php.net:
========================================
(no packages installed)

Installed packages, channel pear.php.net:
=========================================
Package          Version State
Archive_Tar      1.3.11  stable
Console_Getopt   1.3.1   stable
PEAR             1.9.4   stable
Structures_Graph 1.0.4   stable
XML_Util         1.2.1   stable

Installed packages, channel pecl.php.net:
=========================================
(no packages installed)
```

http_request2 is not included among the installed packages, despite just being told that it was installed.

I can also run the pear install http_request2 command again and it will not give me the

```
ignoring installed package pear/http_request2
```

like it's supposed to, instead it just proceeds with the install.

I ran

```
pear config-get php_dir
```

and found http_request2 in that directory.

I tried changing the `include_path` variable in my `php.ini` file as suggested in this post: [Pear Packages not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15581104/pear-packages-not-working) but it didn't change anything.

I would prefer not to reinstall pear if possible because I'm not experienced with this and don't want to accidentally end up with two pears, as suggested can happen here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6596669/2718779. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably stumble across the issue I solved in https://stackoverflow.com/a/19177767/282601 - two versions of pear installed.